# What is the sum over the transition rates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

I was looking at the solution to an exercise, and I came over this expression:

$$P_{i\to f} = \sum \limits_{f}    {2 \pi \over \hbar }\; |\langle f |\hat V | i \rangle |^2  \delta(E_{fi}-E),$$

where I simplified this but it is in effect what the expression is a sum over the [Fermi golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) first order for the transition rate, summing over the final states. I would like to know why this sum is showing up and what it could mean in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the total transition rate for a transition to occur. For instance, in a scattering experiment, there is a probability that an incoming particle will or will not be scattered  by the target. If the quantity in which one is interested is the probability that a particle is scattered, then the quantity you have given above would give you the answer. This is because it gives the probability of scattering out of the initial state into all final states. This is not  always the quantity that one is always interested in in a scattering experiment, however.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just one more thing i by accident mixed up $\rho(E_{fi}-E)$ and $\delta(E_{fi}-E)$ do i guess right your answere is then still accurate? I updated the question to correct it.

Comment: I suppose it does not really make sense to have an index $f$ on though? If we sum over all final states it would make sense to get rid of it right?